Node Js not redirecting after post request
I have a small application where I send fetch request to Node.js server  from JS  and the server redirects to another route. But the server is not redirecting without giving any error.
Javascript Code
  async function sendrollno(rollno) {
            console.log("send roll no called");

            const options = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    rollno: rollno
                }),
            };

            try {
                await fetch("http://localhost:3000/barcode", options);
                console.log('POST request successful');
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error during POST request:', error);
                // Handle errors as needed
                throw error;
            }
        }


Server Side code
router.post("/barcode",  (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.body);
        const message = "sample";
   
        return res.redirect("/register");

    } catch (error) {


        console.error("Error:", error);
        res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
    }
});



router.get("/register", verifyUser, async (req, res) => {
 
    const msg = req.query.msg || null;


    console.log(msg)


    res.render("register", { username: req.user.username, message: msg, student: null, event: null})


})


I'm quite sure it is redirecting. Check the network tab. However you ignore the response from fetch, otherwise you would see the response from the redirected page there. Also keep in mind this has no effect on the currently browsed page, it only affects your fetch request, because the redirection happens during the fetch and not during a browser form submit or navigation. If you want to navigate to a new page in the browser, you need to do so yourself.

Does this answer your question? redirect after a fetch post call - note that the accepted answer is actually wrong, read the other answers too.
